# Doubts over this two variables integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate $$\int_A x \ dxdy$$
Where $$A = \{(x, y) \in\mathbb{R}^2;\ e^{-4}\leq e^{-x} \leq y \leq e^{-2}\}$$

I have troubles in interpreting the bounds.

About the bounds for $x$ I thought to do

$$e^{-4} \leq e^{-x} \leq e^{-2}$$

Hence

$$-4 \leq -x \leq -2$$ that is $$4 \geq x \geq 2$$ so $x \in [2, 4]$

About $y$ I am perplexed instead. How do I proceed?

Comment: I cannot understand the part $dx\,dx$.  Should it be $dx\,dy$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to graph everything via Desmos. This will help give you a visual aid as we try this problem.

As you suggested, $-4 \leq -x \leq -2$, which gives us $2 \leq x \leq 4$. Notice that we also have the description that $e^{-x} \leq y \leq e^{-2}$. This actually gives us the bounds for integration in the y-direction! *(Looking at Desmos, you'll notice that this is the region above $y = e^{-x}$ and below y = $e^{-2}$, from x = 2 to x = 4)*

So, we will have $\int_{dA} (x) dxdy = \int_{2}^{4} \int_{e^{-x}}^{e^{-2}} (x) dy dx $

You may (appropriately) wonder how/why I changed the order of integration...The short answer is that there's nothing "funny" going on with our region/bounds (everything is continuous, no holes, etc etc), so Fubini's Theorem holds and we can swap the order of integration no problem.

Comment: Thank you, really clear!

Comment: It should be $-x$ not $x$  here $-4 \leq x \leq -2$

Comment: Thanks! Fixing now.

Answer (score 4):

Draw the graphs: $e^{-4}, e^{-x}, e^{-2}$

[image: a]

So the region is this shaded area:

[image: b]

Will that help?

Comment: Thank you! This helps indeed!